# How to initialize Drive Service with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I need to initialize a Drive Service in my GAE application. I am using OAuth 2.0 with 3-legged. I Use regular Google accounts (no Service Account). I am trying:

```
GoogleCredential credentials = usuarioService.getGoogleCredentials();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials).build();
```

And I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MAJOR_VERSION
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.<clinit>(Drive.java:48)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder.build(Drive.java:8243)
```

OAuth 2.0 flow authorization is working but accessing to Drive I get error mentioned above.

I don't think my GoogleCredentials are wrong because I use the same method to get authorization in order to use Google Picker.

Thew way how I get GoogleCredential from the user is:

```
GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .build()

    .setRefreshToken(user.getOAuth2RefreshToken()) 
    .setAccessToken(user.getOAuth2AccessToken()); //previous Access Token
```

Could you help me?

Diego.

**UPDATE**
I have updated Drive Library to [the last one](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) (v2) and google-api-client 1.18 and it is still not working.

Now I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.services.drive.Drive
```

**UPDATE 2**
Thinking about I am doing something wrong when I rebuild the GoogleCredential Object, I have tried to call to Drive.Builder() when I request the original Credential from the Authorization flow:

```
final GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authCode).setRedirectUri(callback).execute();     
Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
// Calling to Drive Service
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
```

I get the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MAJOR_VERSION
```

**I do the same with Calendar and I get the same error**

I am using the next libraries:
google-api-client 1.18

google-api-client-servlet 1.18

google-api-service-drive-v2-1.18

google-http-client 1.18

google-http-client-jackson 1.18

google-oauth-client 1.18

Comment: Have you turned on the Drive API in GAE? https://console.developers.google.com/project

Comment: It is turned on @jedison and I'm working on local with Eclipse by the way.

Comment: And you've enabled the Drive SDK for the project: "Drive SDK is not active on this project". https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:<your_project_id>

Comment: Yes. I have different users in my applications. Groups and individual user. I use Service Account and OAuth 1.0 with groups and it's working. I am not able to use SA with individual user and I'm using OAuth 2.0 and doesn't work.

Comment: Have you compared with drEdit sample?

Comment: Yes. It uses Credential Object and I'm using Google Credential. I think this object is built fine because I'm using with Google Picker.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

After of a lot of cup of coffee, I found the mistake.

I have cleaned my project of some libraries and I'm using 1.15 version of Google libraries and it is working (the same code).